# Android Studio 4.1.1 проблемы с R.jar

Tags: android

После обновления на 4.1.1 наблюдаются постоянные проблемы с запуском приложения. Ход действий такой:

- первый запуск приложения проходит нормально - оно запускается на реальном устройстве через шнурок;
- приложение на телефоне не закрываю, в студии Run и Build секции не закрываю (внизу которые, в строке с Logcat-ом);
- решаю изменить что-то в коде;
- внес изменения;
- запускаю Run или Build;
- вываливается сообщение:

  `C:\path_to_application\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.`

Что делал:

- Build -> Clean/Rebuild;
- закрывал приложение на телефоне;
- закрывал секции Run и Build;
- пробовал удалять файл R, к которому не удается получить доступ - удалить не дает при активной студии;
- запускал приложение через "Apply Changes and restart activity";
- делал Invalidate Cache.

ноль эффекта и помогает только перезапуск студии, но это же, блин, не нормально!!!

Еще очень часто при очередной попытке сбилдить или запустить приложение высыпается такая штука:

```
Unable to delete directory 'C:\path_to_application\app\build'
  Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
  - C:\path_to_application\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar
  - C:\path_to_application\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug
  - C:\path_to_application\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar
  - C:\path_to_application\app\build\intermediates
```

Помогите кто может, кто может помогите...

---

Пока писал прошло минут 10-15 - все стало запускаться при вот такой картине:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте потереть в проекте вручную папки build (в корне проекта и в app модуле). Также потереть папки `.idea/libraries` и `gradle`. Также может помочь `Invalidate cache and restart` в самой студии.

Comment: Invalidate вообще не помогает - как будто и не делал ничего.
После затирки папок стало легче до следующего запуска Run.

Comment: Нашла ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547695/why-do-i-get-file-is-used-by-another-process-errors-when-i-run-the-project-wit), нужно просто прописать в одном файле строку

Comment: Супер! Кажется помогло, буду тестить, спасибо!